# Determine if any element with a given name has a particular value

Tags: xpath

Given this XML fragment (I've removed superfluous fluff):

```
<Event name="DataComplete">
   <Task id="d20a0053-7678-43ba-bc8a-ece24dcff15b"/>
     <DataItems>
       <DataItem name="Survey" type="task">
         <Value status="NotStarted" taskId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
       </DataItem>
       <GroupDataItem name="CT_Visit"> --- this may repeat
         <ItemGroup id="1" >
           <DataItem name="Special Contractor" type="string">Yes</DataItem>
```

What xPath expression will determine if any DataItem with name="Special Contractor" has the value "Yes".

I'm trying something like this:

```
  Yes = /Event/Task/DataItems/GroupDataItem/ItemGroup/DataItem/@[normalize-space() = 'Special Contractor']
```

and many variations usually resulting in "invalid xPath expression".

Any clues most welcome.  Thanks!

[EDIT]

Thanks for the answers Jiri and Will.  Will was close, but as my question states, I'm trying to determine if any* element has the value `Yes`.  I should have been more explicit in saying that I need a boolean, true or false.  Adapting Will's answer led me to this:

```
"Yes" = //Event/Task/DataItems/GroupDataItem/ItemGroup/DataItem[@name='Special Contractor']
```

This returns a simple `Boolean='true'` or `Boolean='false'`.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/Event/DataItems/GroupDataItem/ItemGroup/DataItem[@name = "Special Contractor"][. = "Yes"]
```

Returns the `DataItem` in question. Note that this will be a sequence of matching `DataItem` elements if there are more than one. If you just want a boolean:

```
exists(/Event/DataItems/GroupDataItem/ItemGroup/DataItem[@name = "Special Contractor"][. = "Yes"])
```

(as an aside; I removed `Task` from the xpath, since it's not actually an ancestor of the `DataItem` in the XML fragment you posted, even though the indentation makes it look like it is.)

Comment: Thanks Will.  Please see my edit.  For whatever reason, at least in the testers I'm using, `exists(...)` results in an invalid expression.  `"Yes" = //...` works a treat.

Comment: @Simon ah, sorry; that's probably because `exists()` was introduced in XPath 2.0; you might well still be using 1.0. In any case, sounds like you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `xpath`

```
/Event/Task/DataItems/GroupDataItem/ItemGroup/DataItem[@name='Special Contractor']
```

for following xml:

```
<Event name="DataComplete">
   <Task id="d20a0053-7678-43ba-bc8a-ece24dcff15b">
     <DataItems>
       <DataItem name="Survey" type="task">
         <Value status="NotStarted" taskId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
       </DataItem>
       <GroupDataItem name="CT_Visit"> --- this may repeat
         <ItemGroup id="1" >
           <DataItem name="Special Contractor" type="string">Yes</DataItem>
     </ItemGroup>
       </GroupDataItem>
     </DataItems>
   </Task>
   ...
</Event>
```

If the task is really non-pair element, then omit it from the xpath expression.